# Having trouble with accordion with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My accordion works fine but I try to click on an already opened tab and it doesn't close back and also I want my accordion to close as one tab is opened the rest of the other tabs close.

Here is the code:

```
    $(function(){
  var heading = $('h1');

  heading.on('click', function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    $('div.content').addClass('hidden');
  target.next('div.content').removeClass('hidden');

   })
});
```

Comment: Rather than changing the classes yourself, have you tried triggering a click on the tab so jquery ui handles the collapsing for you?

Comment: @Taplar how would I go about doing that? .trigger()? .not()?

Comment: can you share your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `HTML` code is like below,

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div class="content hidden">
    Title 1 Content
</div>
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div class="content hidden">
    Title 2 Content
</div>
<h1>Title 3</h1>
<div class="content hidden">
    Title 3 Content
</div>
```

add this jquery

```
$(function(){
    // hiding rest of the content block (optional), its already hidden in html code by css class
    $('div.content').addClass('hidden');  
    $('h1').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).next('div.content').hasClass('hidden')){
            $(this).next('div.content').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
        }else{
            $(this).next('div.content').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input but I forgot to mention that I want my accordion to close as one tab is opened so as a person opens a tab and then decides to open another one the first they opened closes.

Comment: @JosephCornelio, I have updated my answer, please check it. i hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much, but how I would go about changing the code to have each tab collapsible or when a person clicks on an already opened tab it can close back. @AnfathHifans

Comment: It works but now as one tab is opened, it doesnt close the rest or the other tabs dont collapse. @AnfathHifans